# Get last element after last slash with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

Assuming a string like http://domain.com/aaaa/bbb/ccc/ddd

I want to use a .htaccess file to get the last element, in this case ddd.

I am using:

RewriteRule (.*)/$ ?pt=$1 [L]

But it only works with a trailing slash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because your regex includes a trailing slash.

Try:

```
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/?$ ?pt=$1 [L]
```

The question mark after the slash means "zero or one".  If you don't want that behavior, change the regex accordingly.

**Edit:**

Because the rewrite directives will be re-run after a rewrite is done (at least in per-directory context), it is important to ensure that a rule will not be re-run after you have already achieved the desired rewrite.  There are multiple ways to accomplish this goal, but one is:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !pt
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/?$ ?pt=$1 [L]
```

The point of the `RewriteCond` is to prevent the `RewriteRule` from being applied when there is already a query string with `pt` in it somewhere, which would be a clue that the rewrite has already happened.  More complicated rules might require more or different `RewriteCond` directives.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but with the question mark apache returns a 500 error.

Comment: @edelgado I doubt the question mark is the problem there.  I _may_ be remembering my regex syntax for mod_rewrite incorrectly, though.  What is the error message from apache's error log for your site?

Comment: the message is 
[Tue Mar 22 16:43:09 2011] [error] [client 213.141.22.130] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: @edelgado OK, I think I know what the problem is.  Edit coming shortly.

Answer (score 1):

It works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ /index.php?content=$1 [L]
```

It will change the following URL:

```
http://example.com/anypage
```

into

```
http://example.com/index.php?content=anypage
```

But it'll override everything and ignore parameters. Therefore it's better to
add an extra restrictions.